# Is it possible to enable overflow checks in `--release` build in Rust?

Tags: rust

In `--debug` mode Rust, integer overflow is detected and it results in `panic!()`. Then, is it possible to enable this check in `--release` build **without any additional compile option nor methods such as `checked_add()`**? Pseudo code:

```rust
#[force(overflow_check)]

fn main() {
    //...
}
```

If possible, totally ignoring `--release` options is ok. Pseudo code:

```rust
#[forbid(optimization)]

fn main() {
    //...
}
```

<sub>Why *without any additional compile option*? Because I'd like to enable overflow check in competitive programming environment in which I have no control over how my code is built.</sub>

Comment: Not really.  There’s the `-Coverflow-checks` compilation flag which you can configure Cargo to set when compiling using a given profile (eg its release profile) or with a build script, or you can explicitly use non-overflowing operations in your code eg checked/saturating/wrapped function calls.  But there’s no way out of the box to do what you want in your code itself.  The only thing I can think of would be to write a preprocessor that you could then invoke as a crate-level proc macro: it would rewrite all overflowable operations into their checked alternatives.  But what a horror!

Comment: You could use [`#![deny(clippy::arithmetic)]`](https://rust-lang.github.io/rust-clippy/master/index.html#arithmetic) to deny the normal math operations, requiring you to always used `checked_`, etc

Comment: It’s worth adding that both my absolutely awful macro suggestion and also @PitaJ’s lint suggestion will both only affect the crates to which they’re applied and (unlike the compiler flag) won’t affect overflows in any dependencies.  My macro suggestion will also suffer from the lack of type resolution unless your preprocessor includes large parts of the compiler.

Comment: Are you able to use nightly features?

Comment: You can define a wrapper types for integers that panic on overflow, but this will also not affect dependencies.

Comment: @Locke No (in competitive programming environment). But if you have any solutions which work only for nightly, I'm personally interested in it.

Comment: For anyone finding this question who is using the `cargo` build system, you can set `overflow-checks = true` in `[profile.release]` in `Cargo.toml`. https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/profiles.html
(Not posting this as an answer since the OP indicates a competetive programming environment, where usually only a source file is submitted.)